# Generate a pom.xml file for multi-module Gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, pom.xml, maven-plugin, dependency-management

I'm trying to generate a pom.xml file for my multi-module Gradle project.

My `settings.gradle` file looks as follows:

```
include 'moduleOne'
include 'moduleTwo'
include 'moduleThree'
```

Each one of the submodules may or may not declare its own dependencies, and I would like for all of them to be included into the result "pom.xml" file.

When using `maven` Gradle plugin as follows:

```
/* my buildscript... */

task createPom  {
    pom {
        project {
            groupId 'org.test'
            artifactId 'test'
            version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
        }
    }.writeTo('pom.xml')
}
```

in the `build.gradle` of the root project a "pom.xml" with no dependencies is generated, which is no surprise - the root project itself declares no dependencies.

When creating the `createPom` task in the `subprojects` closure, many pom files that contain dependencies are generated, but I would like to have 1 "pom.xml" with all of the dependencies.

Is there a way I can automatically merge all of my dependencies into one super "pom.xml" file?

Comment: Why do you want a single `pom.xml` instead of the usual setup which is one metadata file per project? Without that information, only a mechanical answer is possible but it might end up not applicable to your problem.

Comment: @LouisJacomet In my case I have 2 subprojects (A and B) where A depends on B, but the only one I'm deploying to Maven is A, my B subproject will be added to A's fat jar file, but I don't want to add B's dependencies to my fat jar, so that's why in my case I'd like to list B's dependencies in A's pom file.